# Linux Mint kernel issue

Tags: linux, power, kernel

I had a kernel update yesterday on Linux Mint 18 and now everytime i try to plug in my power or disconnect my power it just freezes completely and doesn't do anything

System info

- OS: Mint 18 sarah
- Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.4.0-51-generic
- CPU: Intel Core i7-6700HQ CPU @ 3.5GHz
- RAM: 5150MiB / 15919MiB

Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this ? I have read about downgrading the kernel but i don't know if that's a great idea.

Also part of this, not completely related but kernel related
i get this error all the time when looking in syslog or when shutting down

```
Dec  1 10:10:36 DedSec kernel: [  318.395065] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:   device [8086:a110] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Dec  1 10:10:36 DedSec kernel: [  318.395067] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
Dec  1 10:10:36 DedSec kernel: [  318.497528] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e0
Dec  1 10:10:36 DedSec kernel: [  318.497535] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e0(Receiver ID)
```

EDIT:

Requested bug report link: https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1646424

requested output of dpkg -l *-generic

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                          Version             Architecture        Description
+++-=============================-===================-===================-===============================================================
un  linux-generic                 <none>              <none>              (no description available)
ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-21-generi 4.4.0-21.37         amd64               Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-45-generi 4.4.0-45.66         amd64               Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-47-generi 4.4.0-47.68         amd64               Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-51-generi 4.4.0-51.72         amd64               Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
un  linux-headers-generic         <none>              <none>              (no description available)
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic  4.4.0-21.37         amd64               Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-45-generic  4.4.0-45.66         amd64               Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-47-generic  4.4.0-47.68         amd64               Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic  4.4.0-51.72         amd64               Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-ge 4.4.0-21.37         amd64               Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-45-ge 4.4.0-45.66         amd64               Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-47-ge 4.4.0-47.68         amd64               Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-51-ge 4.4.0-51.72         amd64               Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
un  linux-image-generic           <none>              <none>              (no description available)
ii  linux-kernel-generic          4.4.0-21            all                 The Linux kernel.
ii  linux-tools-4.4.0-47-generic  4.4.0-47.68         amd64               Linux kernel version specific tools for version 4.4.0-47
```

Comment: Fill a bugreport: https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint

Comment: i did that, but i want to have a fix around this so i can continue to use my system until the bug has been resolved
also, you have said this on my post on stackkoverflow

Comment: @Jesse, On boot, press shift to get the grub menu, select advanced options then choose a previous kernel. See if you get the same behavior.

Comment: The workaround is booting the previous working kernel.

Comment: Thank you @user.dz that worked indeed, i do wonder (i dont know that much of kernels and such) is this a permanent fix or do i need to do this everytime i boot, oh and also i get grub loader by default because of a side installation of windows

Comment: @Jesse, To make a permanent  workaround, you could set a DPKG pin to skip that version or hold all kernel updates, up to you? Add the output of `dpkg -l *-generic` to the question. Also add the link to the bug report and a note that you are looking for a workaround.

Comment: well im most likely going to install newer updates anyway even kernel, but its nice to know how to make it permanent :) even if its just to skip over this 1 version that bugs out.  and could you explain how to set a dpkg pin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using kernel auto update, no need for DPKG pin (explained below). You would just uninstall that kernel version.

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-4.4.0-51-generic linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-51-generic
```

Pin Method:

1. Create a new APT preference file

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/preferences.d/99_mypin.pref
   ```
2. Put lower priority for that version

   ```
   Package: linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic 
   Pin: 4.4.0-51.72
   Pin-Priority: 1
   ```

Comment: could you add how to remove that :) or can i just use apt purge?

Comment: @Jesse, yes updated my answer.

Comment: dpkg: warning: while removing linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic, directory '/lib/modules/4.4.0-51-generic' not empty so not removed 
i got that error message at the end? is it just clearing folder and trying again?
i think i found my answer, i cleared the folder and tried to run purge again and nothing was deleted, so i guess its alright

Comment: @Jesse, it is ok, leave it, you may have a manually installed a driver that put something or you added something yourself to that folder.